# OpenWRT always shows only one network interface (`lo`), although there are many in a config

Tags: networking, ifconfig, openwrt

I’m running OpenWRT in VMWare Workstation 12 Player on Windows 10 64bit.

When I run `ifconfig` in my OpenWRT, I always get only one network interface, `lo`. Never more:

[image]

Although there are several interfaces in `/etc/config/network` specified:

[image]

Also, I have set up the second network adapter in my VMWare Workstation settings for this OpenWRT instance:

[image]

[image]

So why only one interface is shown? How can I make `ifconfig` show more interfaces? How can I enable them?

Comment: Are you sure your OpenWRT has support for VMWare virtual network adapters?

Comment: Yes, I'm. I've seen this configuration on other Windows machine with VMWare. I'm trying to repeat it on my Win machine.

Comment: Have you configured the virtual devices in VMWare?  If not ifconfig won't be able to configure them in OpenWRT.

Comment: Have you checked in `lspci` or `dmesg` that your OpenWRT sees the devices? Are you sure you are using the same version of OpenWRT as in the another installation?

Comment: I suspect the interface names are not what you expect them to be. What is the output of `ip l`?